# How to test if a target has two's complement integers with the C preprocessor?

Tags: c

Sometimes it *does* matter if the compiler target for a C compiler has two's complement representation of integers or not, and having the preprocessor making the detection can be useful.

Since the standard requires the MAX/MIN macros from `limits.h` and `stdint.h` to be expressions that can be used in preprocessor conditionals, I think that

```
#include <limits.h>
#if INT_MIN + INT_MAX == -1
# define HAVE_TWOS_COMPLEMENT 1
#endif
```

does the trick, since one's complement and sign/magnitude architectures have symmetrical value ranges for signed integers. The question is, am I missing something here or is there a better way to make such a test in a compiler-agnostic way?

Comment: Just by curiosity, where have you found a machine with one's complement? they are harder to find than a unicorn. Can you try `#if (+0 != -0)`? In theory this should return true on one's complement.

Comment: The existence of stdint types like `int32_t` mean it has 2's complement integers.

Comment: Also, the next version of C will require 2's complement,.

Comment: @David: Well, the standard permits it. So portable code should either deal with it, and non-portable code should test for it and complain instead of doing weird stuff...

Comment: @Shawn: Where did you deduce that int32_t means 2's complement? I have only the C201x working draft, but I didn't find that requirement. int32_t means we have a CHAR_BIT==8 machine, more or less, but where does it fix the integer representation?

Comment: @Alex: partially... e.g. I'm not really convinced that e.g. testing `-0 != 0` on one's complement or sign/mag machine works as expected as number compares go by _value_ not bit pattern, AFAIK. Plus, some of the tests there might invoke UB with regard to integer overflow.
But yes, the question is essentially a superset of mine. thnx.

Comment: @Pearly It's part of the definition of the (optional) fixed-width types. They have to use 2's complement. 7.20.1.1 of the C11 and C17 drafts.

Comment: @Shawn: Do you see anything in the standard that says if a C implementation has the `int32_t` two’s complement type, that the `int` type must also be two’s complement?

Comment: @EricPostpischil No. It's C2X that requires 2's complement for all integers, not just the optional ones from stdint. But with current versions of C, if an implementation provides a intN_t type, it has to be 2's complement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In two’s complement, −1 is encoded as 111...111.

In one’s complement, −1 is encoded as 111...110.

In sign-and-magnitude, −1 is encoded as 100..001.

Therefore, the following detects the encoding of the `int` type:

```
#if   (-1 & 3) == 1
    //  The encoding is sign-and-magnitude.
#elif (-1 & 3) == 2
    //  The encoding is one’s complement.
#elif (-1 & 3) == 3
    //  The encoding is two’s complement.
#else
    //  Not possible in the C standard.
#endif
```

The test offered in the question, `INT_MIN + INT_MAX == -1`, is not reliable because C 2018 6.2.6.2 2 permits “the value with sign bit 1 and all value bits zero” to be a trap representation, in which case `INT_MIN` is −(2<sup>*M*</sup>−1), where *M* is the number of value bits, and `INT_MAX` is 2<sup>*M*</sup>−1, so `INT_MIN + INT_MAX` is zero.

Comment: @Eric: thnx for reminding me of `0x80...0` being a possible trap representation. Considering all the issues, bit masking on `-1` seems the best way to handle the issue.