# Number of conjugate complex pairs

Tags: arrays, c, struct, pointer-arithmetic

I need to write a function which fills array *rez* with the conjugate-complex pairs from the array bounded by p1 and p2. The function returns the number of conjugate-complex pairs placed in the array. Duplicates must not be placed in the sequence. Conjugate-complex pairs are pairs of forms a + bi and a - bi.

This task should be solved using structures and pointer arithmetic. Auxiliary arrays are not allowed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct {
  int im, re;
} complex;
void remove_duplicates(complex *rez, int *number){
    int i,j,k;
    for (i = 0; i < *number; i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < *number; j++) {
      if (rez[i].im == rez[j].im && rez[i].re == rez[j].re) {
        for (k = j; k < *number - 1; k++) {
          rez[k].im = rez[k + 1].im;
          rez[k].re = rez[k + 1].re;
        }
        (*number)--;
        j--;
      }
    }
  }
}
int conjugate_complex(complex *p1, complex *p2, complex *rez) {
  int number_of_pairs = 0;
  while (p1 < p2) {
    if (p1->im == p1->re||p1->im == -1*p1->re) {
      number_of_pairs++;
      rez->re = p1->re;
      rez->im = -1*p1->im;
    }
     rez++;
    p1++;
  }
  remove_duplicates(rez,&number_of_pairs);
  return number_of_pairs;
}
int main() {
    int i;
  complex arr1[5] = {{5, 5}, {3, 3}, {-5, -5}, {5, 5}, {-3, 3}};
  complex arr2[5];
  int vel = conjugate_complex(arr1, arr1 + 5, arr2);
  printf("%d\n", vel);
  for (i=0; i<vel; i++)
    printf("(%d,%d) ",arr2[i].im,arr2[i].re);
  return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT should be:

```
4
(-5,5) (-3,3) (5,-5) (3,3)
```

My output is:

```
5
(-5,5) (-3,3) (5,-5) (-5,5) (3,3)
```

The problem with my code is that it prints duplicates.
Could you help me fix my *remove_duplicates* function?
If I call it in main function it would work. However, I need to call it in the function *conjugate_complex*.

Comment: use `long double` instead of `int` because mathematics have decimals too not just integers

Comment: Don't you need the "pairs" to be in the same struct? "-1*p1->im == p1->re" should be (-1*(p1->im)) == p2->im) && (p1->re == p2->re).  There are other issues...

Comment: arr2 (it's empty) is there just to be as border, it enables arr1 to use pointer arithmetic

Comment: The output, only by happenstance, is actually CORRECT (assuming im = b).  BTW, better to order code as re then im IMO.

Comment: arr1 + 5 overflows.  What do you mean by "bounded by P2 & p2?  Do you want to find pairs among the single values, or just find the pre-defined pairs that are conjugates?  Maybe you should re-write this with those answers.

Comment: I want to find pairs among the single values

Comment: I edited code, now I'm really close to correct output, could someone fix my code?

Comment: @Andrew: `arr1+5` does not overflow. `arr1` has five elements, and the C standard defines the behavior of computing the endpoint.

Comment: 7 mins ago my understnding was/is that arr1={5, 5};arr1+1={3, 3};arr1+2={-5, -5};arr1+3={5, 5};arr1+4={-3, 3};arr1+5 overflows

Comment: Does anyone know how to delete duplicate pairs? I edited code, I think now works fine, but problem are duplicates

Comment: @Andrew: No, `arr1+1={3, 3}` is not correct. `arr1+1` **points to** the element containing 3 and 3. `arr1[1]` or `*(arr1+1)` would be that element. `arr1+5` points to one beyond the last element. This is defined by C 2018 6.5.6 8.

Comment: I'm using C90 standard in my course

Comment: ok, so "arr1+5 does not overflow", but it "points to one beyond the last element"(isn't that "bad"?)

Comment: @Andrew: No, it is not bad. The code is using it as the endpoint for a loop, which is precisely why the C standard defines it. `while (p1 < p2)` enters the loop as long as `p1` points to a valid element of the array and stops it when `p1` reaches the endpoint. The parameter `p2` has the value `arr1+5`.

Comment: Do you know why my function `remove_duplicates` doesn't work?

Comment: Why don't you use a hash-table, then you wouldn't need to worry about duplicate removal?

Comment: @Neil I don't know what hash-tables are and how to implement them. I googled but I don't see how could I use them in this task...

Comment: Why my function `remove_duplicates` doesn't work in function conjugate_complex, but works in main function? I edited code

Comment: Nb, the answer is 3 not 4; `(-3, 3)` and `(3, 3)` are the same 3+/-3i.

Answer (score 0):

To see why it would be nice to have some `O(n)` space, consider what you would do in real life with graph paper. Take each complex number and place a spot in the graph `(re, abs(im))`. In that way, any duplicates get merged into one. This solution is `O(n)`. (Expected, the hash is `O(n)` size, so you have to throw out some information, which will lead to collisions.)

It would be better to not duplicate elements in the first place. Whether you are using a [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) to get around the restriction of not having an array, `O(n)` hash, `O(n log n)` sort, or an `O(n^2)` approach (arguably the simplest,) it would be good to have this function, (in pseudo-code, `<stdbool.h>` is `C99`, use `int`, adornments aside):

```
boolean pair_is_equal(pair a, pair b)
```

Be aware that a `pair` is not semantically equivalent to a `complex`. You can use the same representation (which you've been using, and, considering the output format, the simplest,) but be aware that they represent different things. If you let a `complex` stand in for a `pair`:

```
boolean pair_is_equal(complex a, complex b)
```

then you have to also also check one of `a` or `b`'s complex conjugate, (except `Im[a] == 0 || Im[b] == 0`.) It might also be useful care about 2's-compliment `INT_MIN`, which is out of the domain of `abs` and will not have a complement ([how to test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64843863/2472827).)